# Kerning based on the length of Text

Tags: kerning

I am using the `flagderiv` package for proofs but it has no way of putting text before the line number so I have just used `\kern` to put the text where I want it, but this then misaligns the comments.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
   \usepackage{flagderiv}

\begin{document}

\noindent Formula: 
\begin{flagderiv}
   \step{}{P\implies Q}{}
   \step{}{Q\implies R}{commment}
   \assume{}{P}{}
      \step{}{Q}{\kern-115pt 1\&3\kern115pt comment}
      \step{}{R}{\kern-115pt 2\&4}
   \conclude{}{P\implies R}{}
\end{flagderiv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is close to what I want it to look like but the comments are not aligned so I was hoping there is some way of kerning the second comment based on the length of the 1&3.

I was looking into using `\widthof` but couldn't figure out how to use it for my purpose. I am quite new to latex so I maybe missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you so much! That does exactly what I wanted! How would I provide a test file in the future?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that makes sense, I completely forgot that that might be useful! Is it correct now?

Comment: yes thanks, actually in this case I see it really was trivial as you'd mentioned the package in text but you'd be surprised how often fragments posted end up using commands from several unmentioned packages and it's a pain to guess how to run them (so usually I don't even try:-) (+1)

Comment: Good to know, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\makebox[0pt][r]{1\&3\hspace{100pt}}Comment
```

so the 1&3 takes no space so does not disturb the comment, but is offset to the left.